# wget file download ftp waitfor() hangs

Tags: java

I am trying to download a XML file from a FTP server with **wget** in my Java programm. 
I have to wait until it finishes the download.

```
String command = "WGET -O "
    +props.getProperty("xmlFolder")+""+
    + rs.getString("software")
    + ".xml ftp://"+props.getProperty("ftpUser")
    +":"+props.getProperty("ftpPasswort")+"@"+rs.getString("xmlPfad");

System.out.println(command); 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

p.waitFor();
System.out.println("downloaded!");
```

Without the `waitfor()` it works perfectly, but with this function it stucks after 2-3 MB are downloaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the expected download size?

Comment: now the maximum size is about 6mb. but in the future it could be a little bit more.

Comment: And it doesn't throw any exceptions?

Comment: nope. it just stops downloading. but when i stop the programm, it finishes the download, what is also a little bit strange

Comment: Do you access files in the download-directory from another thread?

Comment: no, this is the only thread that is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use the --quiet option for wget?

EDIT 1:

The pipe's write side (child process) might be full.

EDIT 2:

From openjdk-6-src-b20-21_jun_2010

In jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/UNIXProcess_md.c (at least for a UNIX system) we can see how Java launches a new child process and how it is using pipe to redirect stdout and stderr from child (wget) to parent process (Java)